# TeX to C/executable

Tags: tex-core

It is possible to program in TeX and it is a Turing complete language as C. Is there any way to translate a program in TeX into C and vice versa? If so, how to correspond C instructions with TeX's ones? In other words, how to map C's preprocessor directives, functions, i/o, memory management and so on with TeX's available constructions? If one can do without this translation, then how to compile TeX sources and obtain the executable?
[P.S.: I have not read the TeXbook yet, maybe I would find the answers there. But I am so curious -- I used to think TeX was a markup language for making documents but now I see it is a complete programming language]

Comment: you can not generate a binary from a tex document. Turing completeness does not imply you can make an executable. You could of course write a C program to a text file.

Comment: Such a mapping is theoretically possible, but that doesn't mean it is actually practically feasible - C and TeX have very different designs so it will be extremely complex (and slow) to map one onto the other. Compare with actual [Turing machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine), they are also Turing complete, but it's not a good idea to try an run actual C code on a Turing machine.

Comment: I've found a paper http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb11-3/tb29greene.pdf. There is a a code in TeX of Basic interpreter. How to run it? Otherwise, what to do with a code in TeX if it cannot be converted to an executable?
D. Knuth designed a WEB language as well. I've read it is translated into Pascal or C and then is compiled into a binary. The Tangle program translates WEB to Pascal and Web2C translates WEB to C. I thought maybe the same is with TeX.

Comment: Turing competeness just tells you that within tex you can add counters `\advance\count0 by 1` and have if comparisons like `\ifnum\count0=7 X\else Y\fi`  That is _all_ it tells you.  In principle you can program any algorithm using those constructs. In principle.

Comment: the basic interpreter for example doesn't make executable binary object, it just takes normal text input but in basic rather than classic tex syntax and outputs the results as text to the the terminal and log file.

Comment: C to TeX is possible via [`avremu`](https://ctan.org/pkg/avremu) which emulates an 8-Bit processor in TeX, but that is limited and *slow* and your programs have to be compilable with `avr-gcc`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I have understood.